# Ubuntu Virtual Machine Hard Drive re-size (GParted)

Tags: partitioning, virtualbox, hard-drive, gparted

I have changed the size of the vhd. I am running GParted from an iso through Oracle VirtualBox Manager. Gparted will not let me add the extra memory unallocated to the main partition. Can anyone please help?

Print Screen of GParted:

[image]

Note- size is 40Gb, allocated memory is 15GB and unallocated memory is 23GB.

Comment: Your extended partition sda2 is in the way. Move it all the way to the right to allow for growth of sda1

Comment: The unallocated space is behind an extended partition that contains swap, it is no directly adjacent to /dev/sda1. You'll need to move the extended partition to the end of unallocated space first, and then extend sda1.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is, booted to the Ubuntu Live DVD or USB flash drive, start gparted, delete partitions sda5, then delete sda2. Then resize sda1 (maximum to the right - leave some room for a swap partition 1x the size of RAM). Then create a new swap partition in the remaining unallocated space. Right click on this new swap partition and issue a `swapon` command. Reboot.

In terminal, type `sudo blkid` and note (and copy to the clipboard) the UUID of the swap partition that you just created. Then type `sudo gedit /etc/fstab` and change the UUID of the swap partition, to the new value you just recorded (paste from the clipboard). Save and Quit. Reboot.

Questions? Problems? Let us know how you do! Cheers, Al